# Home page is not loading without index.php in url, example.com/index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp , Now the home page shows a white blank screen when I load the root domain name eg: conia.net. But the page is loading when we add index.php to the url eg: conia.net/index.php. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What statuscode does the white screen send? Can you add `index.php` to `DirectoryIndex` to resolve it?

Comment: Well need your htaccess file if you changed it (cakephp default .htaccess file works fine if my memory does not fail me), if not what is your apache host configuration (possibily virtual host), specifically what is the DirectoryIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the apache documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), Directory index directive. Maybe you are on a host that doesn't allow you access to the main apache config, if so you could try to make a `.htaccess` file with this config inside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the **mod_rewrite** module in your domain, you can find this module in your **httpd.conf**.

Essentially, your domain is ignoring the .htaccess file. I would contact your host about this if you are using a shared hosting service.

CakePHP already makes use of a .htaccess file to properly route your application, but it's being ignored due to the server settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

on top of your .htaccess. This will load `/index.php` by default when loading: `http://example.com/`